# Python list of indexes

Tags: python

I would like to get the indexes of a given list (images) and put it into a list.

So far I've tried:

```
list(images)
```

But this only returns itself.

```
list(images.keys())
```

But this gives me an error that images has no attribute keys

Is there a way to get all the indexes into its own list?

Comment: Oh wow thats a great solution. Perfect. Yes. Please post and i'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply create a `range` as long as the list:

```
range(len(images))
```

This returns Range object, which is usable in most of the same contexts as a list. If you really wanted it as a list however, you could just put the range in a list:

```
list(range(len(images)))
```

Comment: One more question, is it possible to start with 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @MatthewSemik Yes. If you reference the documentation for `range`, you'll see that the first argument to `range` can be the starting value.